# How to specify dependencies in Python

Tags: python, dependencies, setup.py, requirements.txt

I came across a python library which has docs, which start like this:

> Quickstart
>
> Include foolib in your requirements.txt file.

AFAIK dependencies should be specified via `install_requires` in `setup.py`.

Should I talk the maintainer of the library and create a pull-request for the docs?

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable. The difference is that specifying something in your `install_requires` will auto-download / install that package when you install the package using setup.py. Having a `requirements.txt` makes it easier to see at a glance what the requirements are. I personally prefer seeing libraries with a `requirements.txt`, since I can install all those requirements with `pip` into my virtualenv and be able to update them quickly if needed.

Comment: setup.py is more flexible, requirements.tx is easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Somehow I hate docs containing "OR".

Answer (score 0):

Add your dependencies in a requirements file and then parse this file in the setup.py. This will help you to:

- Easily install dependencies without installing the entire package through pip
- Get only one source for your dependencies
- Get all way to install your package available (pip, easy_install, command line, etc...)